# Why can't I get a bold Greek letter?

Tags: math-mode, bold, greek

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{article} % A4 paper and 11pt
 % font size
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
(\mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{\sigma}) \sigma&=\mathbf{0}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But the results show `\mathbf{\sigma}` and `\sigma` the same. Why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the bm-package

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{article} % A4 paper and 11pt
 % font size
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,bm} % Math packages

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
(\mathbf{n}\cdot \bm{\sigma}) \sigma&=\mathbf{0}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works. But do you know why the $\mathbf{\sigma}$ not work? Is it because I lack some fonts that supports the $\mathbf{\sigma}$

Comment: @yuxuan: sigma is defined in a way that it "switch back" to the normal font. You should use `\mathbf` only for normal chars, not for symbols.

Answer (score 6):

Uf, Ulrike Fisher is faster than me ... so I will escape the same prepared solution and add one other possibilities, for symbols instead of `\mathbf{..}` you can use `\boldsymbol{...}`:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{article} % A4 paper and 11pt
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
(\mathbf{n}\cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma}) \sigma &=\mathbf{0}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

You will get almost the same result:
[image]

Comment: The documentation of `amsbsy` (that's automatically loaded by `amsmath`) says that using `bm` is better.